# Hibernate: Modify criteria sqlrestriction to using greater than or equal on date

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Not much experienced on using `sqlRestriction`. Need help to amend below code to using **"greater than or equal"** instead of **"like"**.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
                    "to_char(RELEASE_DATE,'dd-Mon-yy') like ?", "%"
                            + convertDate + "%", StandardBasicTypes.STRING));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first parameter use property name, not DB name.

For second parameter use the actual date object, not the string value of date which you hold in `convertDate` .

Then try:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("ReleaseDate", regularDate))
```

Comment: I have tried the releaseDate property but it doesn't work and it seems to work when I set it to the DB column. Anyway, your answer below of greater equal has helped me resolve the logic which I wanted. Thank you!